# Can not remove files from Qt project in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

for some reason `QtCreator` has added source files from a different revision of a library I am building to the project.

So when I expand the `Sources` folder, I get two folders in it with parts of files from the project from different directories where it is cloned, with different revisions.

When I try to right click and remove a file, it says `"Could not remove file..."`.

How do I remove them? Is this some bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are extra paths in your_project.files and try to remove them.